# Splitting fields of symmetric groups

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Is it true that $k$ is a splitting field of $S_n$ if and only if the characteristic $p$ of $k$ is zero or larger than $n$? The fact that the character table (over $\mathbb C$) has only integer entries smaller or equal to $n$, seems to imply this, or am I mistaken?
If the statement is true, could someone give a citation?

Edit: $k$ is a splitting field of $S_n$ if the $k$-algebra $kS_n$ splits over $k$, i.e. if for every simple ($=$ irreducible) $kS_n$-left-module $M$, we have $\mathrm{End}_{kS_n}(M) \cong k$.

Comment: What does "is a splitting field of $S_n$" mean?

Comment: edited the original post to include a defintion

Comment: To be clear: every field is a splitting field for $S_n$. Let me know if you want a group theory proof. The combinatorics proofs are in places like James's book already mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The irreducible $S_n$-modules are all realizable over the integers. Specifically, there is a family of $\mathbb{Z} S_n$-modules $S^\lambda$ indexed by partitions $\lambda$ of $n$, called *Specht modules*, together with symmetric $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear forms, such that over a field $k$, the quotient by the radical of the form is either zero or irreducible, and the set of non-zero irreducibles obtained this way is a complete set of representatives for the isoclasses of irreducibles. What is true is that the group algebra is semisimple exactly if the characteristic $p$ is bigger than $n$. In general, the blocks are in bijection with the set of $p$-cores of partitions of $n$.

You can read about this in chapter 4 of James' book "The representation theory of the symmetric group".

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why you need $p$ larger than $n$ if non-zero -more precisiely, you don't. In that case, an absolutely irreducible module for a finite group is realizable over the field of its character, and for the symmetric group, this is always the prime subfield.
 This boils down to the fact that Schur indices are trivial over finite fields, which in turn is a consequence of the fact that finite division algebras are fields. It is explained in many standard texts on representation theory, eg Curtis and Reiner.

Comment: I guess, I just added that restraint to ensure semisimplicity, which I did not ask for. Do you have a citation for the result?

Comment: The only thing I was going to add is that the character values lie in the prime field since each $p$-regular conjugacy class is closed under taking $p$th powers.

Comment: I was implicitly using the fact that ordinary character values are integers, since all conjugacy classes are rational, so values of Brauer characters are integers (for the symmetric group, and for any prime)